# Getting particular information out of pcap files

Tags: networking, wireshark, tshark, wifi

I am interested in particular information in the `.pcap` (`Frame control` field). I want to extract it to a text file and then do graph plotting using the extracted data. I can do export to text file using `wireshark` but I am looking for automating the process.

As of now I know that `Tshark` can be used to convert `.pcap` to text files but then it outputs the whole packet. Instead I am interested in only one particular information.

Is there some nice way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some nice way to do this.

Could be.

If the field you wish to extract has a filter, the you can use tshark to output just that field using the `-T` and `-e` switches;

```
tshark -Tfields -e tcp.port -r ....
```

See `tshark -h` for details...

To use wireshark to see the name for a field, click on the field in the details pane and then note the field name shown in the bottom status bar.

Which field(s) specifically do you want ? from what protocol ?

Comment: I will look into it. I have a .pcap file of `802.11` packets and want to extract frame control information.

Comment: The 802.11 Frame Control field is called `wlan.fc`, so try `tshark -Tfields -e wlan.fc -r ....`.